# WooCommerce show additional cart fields based on subtotal

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to show one specific add-on shipping insurance product based on the WooCommerce SubTotal. My code ab-ends on line 10. I think the hide/show process needs a wrapper but I'm unsure how to code it.

I was given a suggestion but I don't know how to implement it...

The suggestion:
It looks like you're trying to use a mixed PHP / javascript approach based on  hiding or showing fields.
Instead, I'd recommend hooking into the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` at a priority greater than 10 (like 20) -- this would let you get all fields from the `$checkout_fields['add_ons']` array, and then you can "unset" some of them based on the cart subtotal (which is significantly easier to grab via PHP instead of javascript).

Anyone who can help... Thank you tons in advance.
My original try at it...

```
<?php
function wc_shipping_insurance_chooser() {
// Set variables
$fifty = 50;
$one_hundred =   100;
$two_hundred =   200;

if (WC()->cart->total >$fifty && WC()->cart->total <$one_hundred ) {
    If( is_cart() ) {
        // Show Insurance cost for $50 - $100
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_10_field' ).show();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_11_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_12_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_13_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_14_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_15_field' ).hide();
    } else {
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_10_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_11_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_12_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_13_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_14_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_15_field' ).hide();
    }

} elseif (WC()->cart->total >$one_hundred && WC()->cart->total <$two_hundred ) {
    If( is_cart() ) {
        // Show Insurance cost for $100-$199
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_10_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_11_field' ).show();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_12_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_13_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_14_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_15_field' ).hide();
    } else {
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_10_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_11_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_12_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_13_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_14_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_15_field' ).hide();
    }


    } else {
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_10_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_11_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_12_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_13_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_14_field' ).hide();
        $( '#wc_checkout_add_ons_15_field' ).hide();
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_shipping_insurance_chooser' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_shipping_insurance_chooser' );

?>
```

Comment: It's kind of impossible to know what your add-on fields are, but it appears that you are trying to mix PHP and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying my [tutorial on checkout fields](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) a bit, this will show "Some field" when the total is between 50-100 and "Another field" when the total is between 100-200.

```
// Add a new checkout field
function kia_filter_checkout_fields( $fields ){
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->total; 
    if( $cart_total > 50 && $cart_total < 100 ) {
        $fields['extra_fields'] = array(
                'some_field' => array(
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'label' => __( 'Some field' )
                    ),
                );
    } else if ( $cart_total > 100 && $cart_total < 200 ) {
        $fields['extra_fields'] = array(
            'another_field' => array(
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'label' => __( 'Another field' )
                )
            );
    }

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'kia_filter_checkout_fields' );

// display the extra field on the checkout form
function kia_extra_checkout_fields(){ 

    $checkout = WC()->checkout; 

    if( ! empty( $checkout->checkout_fields['extra_fields'] ) ){ 

    ?>

    <div class="extra-fields">
    <h3><?php _e( 'Additional Fields' ); ?></h3>

    <?php 
    // because of this foreach, everything added to the array in the previous function will display automagically
    foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['extra_fields'] as $key => $field ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ,'kia_extra_checkout_fields' );
```